# The exterior derivate

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, exterior-algebra

I am trying to show that $d(a \wedge da)=0$ if $k$, the degree of k-form $a$ is even. I have said:

$=da \wedge da + (-1)^k a \wedge d^2a$

I believe the first term is zero due to repeated indices and the second is zero since $d^2=0$. However, a subsequent exercise relies on the fact that $d(a \wedge da)$ is not alway zero if k is odd. Can anybody point out the error that I have made?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla a subsequent exercise relies on the fact it is non-zero for k odd.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I see, you're being a pedant! I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the second term that is always zero (because $d^2a = 0$), no matter what $k$ is. The first term is zero because $da$ has odd degree. In general

$$ x \wedge y = (-1)^{|x||y|} y \wedge x$$

where $|x|,|y|$ are the degrees of $x,y$. In particular, if $x$ has odd degree then $x \wedge x = 0$.

Comment: so my assumption that $da \wedge da$ is necessarily zero is where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As levap writes in their answer, it *is* true that $da \wedge da = 0$ for forms $a$ of even degree $k$: The exterior derivative $da$ has degree $k + 1$, and so by the commutation rule $$\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{|\alpha| |\beta|} \beta \wedge \alpha,$$ (where $|\gamma|$ denotes the degree of $\gamma$) we have $$da \wedge da = (-1)^{(\textrm{odd})(\textrm{odd})} = - da \wedge da ,$$ and so $da \wedge da = 0$.

On the other hand, if $a$ has odd degree, so that $da$ has even degree,
$$da \wedge da = (-1)^{(\textrm{even})(\textrm{even})} = da \wedge da ,$$ which is a tautology.

Indeed, it is possible that for forms $a$ of odd degree that $da \wedge da \neq 0$. A simple example is
$$a := x^1 \,dx^2 + x^3 \,dx^4,$$ on $\Bbb R^4$, for which $da$ is the standard symplectic form, $$da = dx^1 \wedge dx^2 + dx^3 \wedge dx^4 ,$$ and $da \wedge da$ is (a multiple) of the standard volume form, $$da \wedge da = 2 \,dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 .$$

Comment: Am I right in thinking that for $\R^n, n \ge 4$ must hold?

Comment: Yes, but not for a very interesting reason: Since $a$ is odd, we must have $|a| \geq 1$, so that $|da| \geq 2$ and hence $|da \wedge da| \geq 4$, but if $n < 4$ then the only $k$-forms with $k \geq 4$ are trivial. Perhaps more interesting that, by Darboux's Theorem, up to local equivalence (i.e., up to a change of coordinates) this is the only such example in $4$ dimensions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem